# Closing Child Shell with a Button like Red X button

Tags: java, shell, swt

I have a main parent shell and a child shell. The child shell is for some settings. When the settings are done. I would like to close the child shell and continue working with the parent shell. I'm using `display_Settings.dispose();` to close the child shell. But this closes both of the shells(parent and child). When I click only the red X button of the child shell only the child shell closes. This is what I want. How can I achieve it? Also when the child shell is open it is possible to manipulate/click buttons on parent shell. I would like to forbid this until I'm done with the settings in child shell(until I close the child shell).

Below is how I open the child shell in parent shell:

```
    btnSettings.addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent (Event event) { // Button Settings event
            try {
                my_Obect = new My_Object();
                Display display_Settings = Display.getDefault();
                Child_Settings shell_Settings = new Child_Settings(display_Settings, my_Object);
                shell_Settings.open();
                shell_Settings.layout();
                while (!shell_Settings.isDisposed()) {
                    if (!display_Settings.readAndDispatch()) {
                        display_Settings.sleep();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Parent GUI class and Child GUI classes are two different classes, below is how I open the Parent shell:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        GUI_Test shell = new GUI_Test(display);
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Although the Display variables are different, both shells close, actually their names don't matter because they are both different classes. I would be glad if you can help me!

Comment: Please note, that you don't need more than one event loop (the `readAndDispatch()` stuff. One is sufficient.

Comment: @Baz `readAndDispatch()` belong to different objects?

Comment: You've got two `while` event loops. You just need the one in your `main` method

Answer (score 0):

Here goes an example of a Shell with a button that opnes a modal child Shell when selected.

<-- language: lang-java -->

```
Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell( display );
shell.setText( "Shell" );
shell.setSize( 200, 200 );
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
Button button = new Button( shell, SWT.PUSH );
button.setText( "Open Modal Child Shell" );
button.addListener( SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    Shell dialog = new Shell( shell, SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM );
    dialog.setText( "Dialog" );
    dialog.setSize( 200, 200 );
    dialog.open();
  }
} );
shell.open();
while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
  if( !display.readAndDispatch() ) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
```

All interaction with the main shell is prevented while the dialog shell is opened: This is achieved through the `SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL` style flag. The `SWT.DIALOG_TRIM` style flag adds a title bar with a close button to the shell but is otherwise not necessary to get modal behavior.

The dialog shell can be closed with `Esc`. The main loop at the end of the code snippet keeps the application alive until the main shell is closed.